# NPM - Protractor Error 404 when trying to fetch metadata for @types/node

Tags: selenium, types, npm, protractor, q

My problem is that when i try to install Protractor 5.1.2 through npm i get the following error:

> npm ERR! code E404
>
> npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @types/node@^6.0.46

I use the following command in the root directory for installing:

```
npm install protractor@5.1.2 --registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

(I do the reigistry thing because I get a certification error if not)

If I call the command multiple times I get different "Not Found" which are:

- npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @types/q@^0.0.32
- npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @types/selenium-webdriver@~2.53.39

The log can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/bZCSfC35

I'm a beginner regarding npm.

OS: Windows 10

**EDIT:**
I have tried running the following command:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

And I have deleted the node modules folder

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @wswebcreation Sorry for the late answer, but no, I'm not behind a proxy

Comment: Which version of Node and npm are you using?

Comment: @wswebcreation NPM: 5.0.3. Node: 8.1.3. And they have been reinstalled, so they should be clean.

Comment: Has anyone found an answer to this problem yet? I am getting the exact same error. I have npm version 6.1.0 and node version 8.11.1

Comment: @BlockchainDeveloper have you tried connecting to the internet through your phone, and then call the install command?

Comment: That works for me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution to this, for me at least, was to disable the firewall on both my pc and my router.